# Select top from group

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I have model Message:

```
protected $fillable = ['id','text','girl_id','date'];
```

How to choose the last message by date for each girl_id?

My code:

```
$messages=Message::select(['id','text','girl_id','date'])
                    ->groupBY('girl_id')
                    ->orderBY('date')
                    ->take(1)
                    ->get();
```

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Just try this solution

```
 $messages=Message::select(['id','text','girl_id','date'])
                      ->orderBY('date','desc')
                      ->groupBY('girl_id')
                      ->get()
                      ->take(1);
```

Comment: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'a0188141_girls2.messages.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `id`, `text`, `girl_id`, `date` from `messages` group by `girl_id` order by `date` desc)

Comment: Problem in GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

Get last message foe each girl_id:

```
  $messages=Message::select(['id','text','girl_id','date'])
                 ->orderBY('date','desc','girl_id')
                 ->get()
                 ->unique('girl_id')
```